# how to pass variable to a widget

Tags: flutter

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';


class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignIn({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  bool obscureTextPassword = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Card(child: Container(width: 300,child: Column(children: [_emailField(),_passwordField(),
            ],),),);}

Widget _emailField() => const Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 24),
      child: TextField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            hintText: 'Indirizzo Email',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
            icon: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.envelope,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 22,
            )),
      ),
    );

Widget _passwordField() => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8, horizontal: 24),
      child: TextField(
        obscureText: obscureTextPassword,
        style: const TextStyle(
          fontSize: 16,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
          hintText: 'Password',
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
          icon: const Icon(
            FontAwesomeIcons.lock,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: 22,
          ),
          suffixIcon: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  obscureTextPassword = !obscureTextPassword;
                });
              },
              child: Icon(
                  obscureTextPassword
                      ? FontAwesomeIcons.eye
                      : FontAwesomeIcons.eyeSlash,
                  size: 15,
                  color: Colors.black)),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Which variable, where?

Answer (score 0):

Add the variable both to your state class (*`_SignInState`*) and your widget class (*`SignIn`*). Assign them in both constructors. Then pass the variable from the widget class to the state class in `Widget.createState`. You can then access the variable in the build method.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could mention more details. But I'll provide you with an example let me know if it resolves the issue you are facing:

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;

  // Approach 1: Using Positional argument
  // Use this like MyWidget(10);
  const MyWidget(this.value); // <- Use this

  // Approach 2: Using the named argument
  // Use this like MyWidget(value: 10);
  const MyWidget({required this.value}); // <- Or use this

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```